# Thread initiallization

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to speedup the execution of a simulation. This is part of the main function:

```
double computeStart = wtime();
    /* Main loop */

    for (t = 0.0; t < t_end; t += del_t, iters++) {

        setTimestepInterval(&del_t, imax, jmax, delx, dely, u, v, Re, tau);

        ifluid = (imax * jmax) - ibound;

        computeTentativeVelocity(u, v, f, g, flag, imax, jmax,
            del_t, delx, dely, gamma, Re);

        computeRhs(f, g, rhs, flag, imax, jmax, del_t, delx, dely);

        if (ifluid > 0) {
            itersor = poissonSolver(p, rhs, flag, imax, jmax, delx, dely,
                        eps, itermax, omega, &res, ifluid);
        } else {
            itersor = 0;
        }

        if (verbose > 1) {
            printf("%d t:%g, del_t:%g, SOR iters:%3d, res:%e, bcells:%d\n",
                iters, t+del_t, del_t, itersor, res, ibound);
        }

        updateVelocity(u, v, f, g, p, flag, imax, jmax, del_t, delx, dely);

        applyBoundaryConditions(u, v, flag, imax, jmax, ui, vi);
    } /* End of main loop */
    double computeEnd = wtime();
```

I want to parallelise the functions *updateVelocity* and *applyBoundaryConditions* which are in another file. But i do not want to use

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
```

every time these two functions are called as the amount of overhead would be huge. Is there a way I can initiallise the threads only once instead of initiallising them everytime *updateVelocity* and *applyBoundaryConditions* are called. These are the functions:

```
void updateVelocity(float **u, float **v, float **f, float **g, float **p,
    char **flag, int imax, int jmax, float del_t, float delx, float dely)
{
    int i, j;

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax; j++) {
            /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i+1][j] & C_F)) {
                float pcalc = p[i+1][j]-p[i][j];
                float mul = pcalc*del_t;
                float div = mul/delx;
                u[i][j] = f[i][j] - div;
                // u[i][j] = f[i][j]-(p[i+1][j]-p[i][j])*del_t/delx;
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (i=1; i<=imax; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {
            /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
            if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i][j+1] & C_F)) {
                float pcalcv = p[i][j+1]-p[i][j];
                float mulv = pcalcv*del_t;
                float divv = mulv / dely;
                v[i][j] = g[i][j] - divv;
                // v[i][j] = g[i][j]-(p[i][j+1]-p[i][j])*del_t/dely;
            }
        }
    }
}

void applyBoundaryConditions(float **u, float **v, char **flag,
    int imax, int jmax, float ui, float vi)
{
    int i, j;
    // imax is 600
    // jmax is 200
    // the larger the loop iterations the more efficient the parallelisation
    // may not be optimisable under parallelisation
    // 2 threads optimal
    for (j=0; j<=jmax+1; j++) {
        /* Fluid freely flows in from the west */
        u[0][j] = u[1][j];
        v[0][j] = v[1][j];

        /* Fluid freely flows out to the east */
        u[imax][j] = u[imax-1][j];
        v[imax+1][j] = v[imax][j];
    }
    for (i=0; i<=imax+1; i++) {
        /* The vertical velocity approaches 0 at the north and south
         * boundaries, but fluid flows freely in the horizontal direction */
        v[i][jmax] = 0.0;
        u[i][jmax+1] = u[i][jmax];

        v[i][0] = 0.0;
        u[i][0] = u[i][1];
    }

    /* Apply no-slip boundary conditions to cells that are adjacent to
     * internal obstacle cells. This forces the u and v velocity to
     * tend towards zero in these cells.
     */
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)  // decrease runtime by about 9 secs
    for (i=1; i<=imax; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax; j++) {
            if (flag[i][j] & B_NSEW) {
                switch (flag[i][j]) {
                    case B_N:
                        v[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        u[i][j]   = -u[i][j+1];
                        u[i-1][j] = -u[i-1][j+1];
                        break;
                    case B_E:
                        u[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        v[i][j]   = -v[i+1][j];
                        v[i][j-1] = -v[i+1][j-1];
                        break;
                    case B_S:
                        v[i][j-1] = 0.0;
                        u[i][j]   = -u[i][j-1];
                        u[i-1][j] = -u[i-1][j-1];
                        break;
                    case B_W:
                        u[i-1][j] = 0.0;
                        v[i][j]   = -v[i-1][j];
                        v[i][j-1] = -v[i-1][j-1];
                        break;
                    case B_NE:
                        v[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        u[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        v[i][j-1] = -v[i+1][j-1];
                        u[i-1][j] = -u[i-1][j+1];
                        break;
                    case B_SE:
                        v[i][j-1] = 0.0;
                        u[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        v[i][j]   = -v[i+1][j];
                        u[i-1][j] = -u[i-1][j-1];
                        break;
                    case B_SW:
                        v[i][j-1] = 0.0;
                        u[i-1][j] = 0.0;
                        v[i][j]   = -v[i-1][j];
                        u[i][j]   = -u[i][j-1];
                        break;
                    case B_NW:
                        v[i][j]   = 0.0;
                        u[i-1][j] = 0.0;
                        v[i][j-1] = -v[i-1][j-1];
                        u[i][j]   = -u[i][j+1];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /* Finally, fix the horizontal velocity at the  western edge to have
     * a continual flow of fluid into the simulation.
     */

    v[0][0] = 2*vi-v[1][0];
    for (j=1;j<=jmax;j++) {
        u[0][j] = ui;
        v[0][j] = 2*vi-v[1][j];
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You assert that "the overhead would be huge", but, while there certainly is overhead, in any sane library it will not be "huge", because OpenMP runtime libraries maintain a thread pool, so the high cost of creating OS level threads is only paid at the very first parallel region. Other parallel regions should, therefore, cost only slightly more than a  barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i do not want to use
>
> #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)

You need to use `#pragma omp parallel` to create the threads.

Instead of:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=jmax; j++) {
        /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
        if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i+1][j] & C_F)) {
            float pcalc = p[i+1][j]-p[i][j];
            float mul = pcalc*del_t;
            float div = mul/delx;
            u[i][j] = f[i][j] - div;
            // u[i][j] = f[i][j]-(p[i+1][j]-p[i][j])*del_t/delx;
        }
    }
}
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
for (i=1; i<=imax; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {
        /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
        if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i][j+1] & C_F)) {
            float pcalcv = p[i][j+1]-p[i][j];
            float mulv = pcalcv*del_t;
            float divv = mulv / dely;
            v[i][j] = g[i][j] - divv;
            // v[i][j] = g[i][j]-(p[i][j+1]-p[i][j])*del_t/dely;
        }
    }
}
```

try the following

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for private(j)
    for (i=1; i<=imax-1; i++) {
      for (j=1; j<=jmax; j++) {
        /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
        if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i+1][j] & C_F)) {
            float pcalc = p[i+1][j]-p[i][j];
            float mul = pcalc*del_t;
            float div = mul/delx;
            u[i][j] = f[i][j] - div;
            // u[i][j] = f[i][j]-(p[i+1][j]-p[i][j])*del_t/delx;
         }
      }
  }
  #pragma omp for private(j)
  for (i=1; i<=imax; i++) {
      for (j=1; j<=jmax-1; j++) {
        /* only if both adjacent cells are fluid cells */
        if ((flag[i][j] & C_F) && (flag[i][j+1] & C_F)) {
            float pcalcv = p[i][j+1]-p[i][j];
            float mulv = pcalcv*del_t;
            float divv = mulv / dely;
            v[i][j] = g[i][j] - divv;
            // v[i][j] = g[i][j]-(p[i][j+1]-p[i][j])*del_t/dely;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The other loop that you have added the  `#pragma omp for schedule(static)`

```
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)  // decrease runtime by about 9 secs
    for (i=1; i<=imax; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=jmax; j++) {
            if (flag[i][j] & B_NSEW) {
                switch (flag[i][j]) {
```

should not parallelized because there are dependencies between the iterations of the outermost loop namely:

```
            case B_N:
                v[i][j]   = 0.0;
                u[i][j]   = -u[i][j+1];
                u[i-1][j] = -u[i-1][j+1]; // <-- This one
```

among others.